# Handling action in Remix.run without POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, remix.run

I read up on the Remix docs on action and most of information I can find on action is it uses the the form POST with button submit to trigger the action

```
export default function Game() {
    const counter = useLoaderData();

    return (
        <>
            <div>{counter}</div>
            <div>
                <Form method="post">
                    <button type="submit">click</button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

However, how would the action  be triggered in regards to something else like... drag and drop components, where after dropping it should trigger the action post

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`useSubmit` should do what you want.

An example from the [docs](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#usesubmit)

```
import { useSubmit, useTransition } from "remix";

export async function loader() {
  await getUserPreferences();
}

export async function action({ request }) {
  await updatePreferences(await request.formData());
  return redirect("/prefs");
}

function UserPreferences() {
  const submit = useSubmit();
  const transition = useTransition();

  function handleChange(event) {
    submit(event.currentTarget, { replace: true });
  }

  return (
    <Form method="post" onChange={handleChange}>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="darkMode" value="on" />{" "}
        Dark Mode
      </label>
      {transition.state === "submitting" ? (
        <p>Saving...</p>
      ) : null}
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Comment: link to the doc https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#usesubmit

Comment: Thanks @Lorezz though link is already in the answer "Here's an example from the docs" 

Comment: Any idea if useTransition works without JavaScript (in case user has us turned off or is doesn’t load)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can't work without JS like any other AJAX like behaviour. So if the JS failed for whatever reason the form will be submitted using the normal browser behavior and reloading the page.

Comment: how can I do this form post but without a navigate to the specified action? I have a login modal in `/otherpage` whose action points to `/?index` but it navigates to `/`

Comment: @DavidRearte If I understand your question correctly one way could be using `useFetcher`

Comment: @CanRau yes that did the trick, thx